# Updating a table from a table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query that declares a table within it.

```
Declare @t table(tagname nvarchar(50), Value float, timestamp datetime)
```

I then insert some date into this table. Once this is done I want to update another table (already created) from `@t`.

Something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE Optimiser_tagData
SET Optimiser_tagData.value = @t.value
where Optimiser_tagData.tagName = @t.tagName
```

This obviously doesn't work and I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@t"

I am sure I am missing something very easy but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the two tables - `@t` and `Optimiser_tagData`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your update statement should be like below. You have to apply Join between `Table variable` and `Optimiser_tagData`.  And you should run update statement as a whole(Table variable declaration etc)

```
UPDATE Optimiser
    SET Optimiser.value = t.value
    from Optimiser_tagData Optimiser
    join @t t
    on Optimiser.tagName = t.tagName
```

Comment: In my case I had to put  `on Optimiser = t.tagName`